# Swift: Cannot Load the HTML in webView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying to load the `HTML` from the `Web`. This is my `Service class`

```
class WaysToEarnIncentiveServices :HpApiBaseService {

internal static func getWaysToEarnIncentiveServices(memberId : Int, onCompletion : (Bool) -> Void){
    var queryStringKVP : [String:String] = [String:String]()
    queryStringKVP["ClientName"] = String(MemberIdProvider.sharedInstance.memberProfile.client)

    let requestUrl = hpApiBaseUrl+"incentiveManager/earnIncentive"
    get(requestUrl,queryStringKVP: queryStringKVP){(isSuccess, responseString) in
        if(isSuccess && responseString != nil){
print (requestUrl)

        }
   }
  }  
}
```

This is the `ViewController` having the **webView** where i should display the HTML context:

```
import UIKit
class WaysToEarnIncentive: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = "Ways To Earn Incentive"
 CommonUtility.sharedInstance.addBackButton(self)

}

func loadData(){
    SwiftSpinner.show(kLoadingText)
    WaysToEarnIncentiveServices.getWaysToEarnIncentiveServices(MemberIdProvider.sharedInstance.memberId, onCompletion:{(isSuccess:Bool) in
        if(isSuccess){

            SwiftSpinner.hide()
        }
    })
  }

 @IBAction func backClicked(sender:UIBarButtonItem!){
    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
 }
 }
```

Upto fuction **loadData** i have correct url and the context of web is displayed in the console. i wanted this in my view.How can i achieve this? OR any other tricks to load the Html context will be really appreciated.

The output in console is:

```
SUCCESS: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=UTF-8><title> and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by setting this value to `UIWebView` solves your issue :

Just store your response into `htmlString` and then

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Feel free to comment.

Comment: so how can i put those success message of <!DOCTYPE in htmlString? i am stucked in this point

Comment: how do i store the responses to htmlString?

Comment: Just assign response into htmlstring